# Selecting Groups From Pandas Group-By Object That Was Grouped on Multiple Columns

Tags: pandas, group-by

I want to group a pandas df by multiple columns and then select groups from that object while not needing to use all the keys I've grouped the data by.

For example, if I've grouped pandas df by columns A and B:

`g_df = df.groubpby(['A','B'])`

I can then retrieve a group by specifying keys for A and B:

``
specific_group = g_gf.get_group(('A Key','B Key'))

``

My issue is that I would like to use this same group object to select a group that includes all A keys (i.e. only filter by the B key). When I try this I only get errors. Is this possible to do with a single group object?

I've tried:

`g_df.get_group((tuple(g_df['A'].unique()),'B Key'))`

and get a Key Error.

I also tried:

`g_df.get_group(,'B Key'))`

But that return a syntax error.

Comment: No it's not directly possible, you would need another groupby. What is your exact use case?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

As @mozway said, it's not directly possible. So, you have to handle this case yourself to get what you expect.

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
4  2  2
5  1  2
6  1  1
7  2  1
8  1  1
9  2  2
```

And the `DataFrameGroupBy`:

```
>>> g = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fb5b0307e80>

>>> g.groups
{(1, 1): [6, 8],
 (1, 2): [0, 5],
 (2, 1): [7],
 (2, 2): [1, 2, 3, 4, 9]}

>>> g.get_group((1, 2))
   A  B
0  1  2
5  1  2
```

Instead of using `g.get_group` method, you can define your own `get_group` function:

```
def get_group(g, name):
    sr = pd.Series(g.groups)
    loc = np.all([sr.index.get_level_values(lvl) == idx
                      for lvl, idx in enumerate(name)
                      if idx is not None], axis=0)
    return g.obj.loc[np.concatenate(sr[loc].values)]
```

Now, suppose you want to get the group for `b==2` (0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9):

```
>>> get_group(g, (None, 2))
   A  B
0  1  2
5  1  2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
4  2  2
9  2  2
```

For `a==1` (6, 8, 0, 5):

```
>>> get_group(g, (1, None))  # or simply get_group(g, (1,))
   A  B
6  1  1
8  1  1
0  1  2
5  1  2
```